# Gradle 7 & Java 11: No compatible toolchains found for request filter

Tags: java, gradle, java-11

After upgrading to from Gradle 6.7.1 to Gradle 7.4, the following error occurs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':example-project:compileJava'.
> Failed to query the value of extension 'example-extension' property 'enabled'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':example-project:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
      > No compatible toolchains found for request filter: {languageVersion=11, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific} (auto-detect true, auto-download false)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution:

Add this to `build.gradle`:

```
java {
    toolchain {
        implementation = JvmImplementation.J9
    }
}
```

## Explanation

It turned out that the JDK I used was implemented with J9.

At the time of writing, Gradle ignores JDK implemented with J9 unless explicitly set to use it.

This appears to be a bug:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16897#issuecomment-823272229

To check whether your JDK is implemented in J9 or not, run

```
path/to/your/jdk/bin/java -version
```

The output will look something like this:

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.24.0, JRE 11 Linux amd64-64-Bit 20210120_821 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 345e1b09e
OMR      - 741e94ea8
JCL      - 0a86953833 based on jdk-11.0.10+9)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, java 21 made the same problem. I installed java 17 and explicitly declared it in JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying out Kotlin Multiplatform, specifically for JVM and web development, replacing this:

```
jvm {
        jvmToolchain(8)
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
```

with this:

```
jvm()
```

helped me fix the issue.